# Using function fminbnd to determine a maximum?

Tags: matlab, max

I'm trying to locate the x value at which a maximum occurs by taking the negative of my function in fminbnd.  However, I keep encountering an error. Can someone please correct my syntax or give the correct syntax to solve this problem?  This is an example:

```
>> func

func = 

    @(x)(x)^3+2*(x)^2
```

I've tried

```
>> xmax = fminbnd('-func',1,3)
>> xmax = fminbnd('-func(x)',1,3)
>> xmax = fminbnd(-func,1,3)
```

and various others, but I still get an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
fminbnd(@(x) -func(x),1,3)
```

Comment: in what way is your solution different that [@Luis's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20851161/1714410)?

Comment: @Shai this answer came up before Luis added this code to his answer. So the downvote is unjustified.

Answer (score 1):

For **minimum**: use

```
fminbnd(func, 1, 3)
```

In this syntax, `func` is a [function handle](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) (as you have defined in your example).

Alternatively, you can define the function directly within `fminbnd`, using a [temporary function handle to an anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
fminbnd(@(x)(x)^3+2*(x)^2, 1, 3)
```

For **maximum**: define a temporary function directly within `fminbnd`:

```
fminbnd(@(x)-func(x), 1, 3)
```

Comment: I understand this, but this would only give me the min location, where as I am trying to locate the max value

Comment: @vdhalla Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Please see update